# Choosing WiFi network from app on Android Things device (Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I'm running Android Things on a Raspberry Pi 3 with a touch screen attached.

I would like to be able to access and update wifi settings in my app. I.e. be able to show a list of scanned wifi networks and let the user pick one and type in a password.

This would be useful when bringing the device to another building with a different wifi network, for example.

Is this possible? Or is the only way to change the wifi connection to do one of the actions described here: https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#connecting_wi-fi

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are APIs which can be used to [setup Wi-Fi networks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#addNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration)) programmatically. This means you can do all the scanning and connecting inside of your app.

Comment: GAH I figured it out... I was forgetting to `enableNetwork(...)` after adding it.